# How do you set the focus on a TextBox when ListViewItem is clicked?

Tags: c#, mvvm, textbox, listviewitem, setfocus

I'm creating an UWP app using XAML and C#. Each ListViewItem in the ListView contains a TextBox. When I click/select a ListViewItem, I would set the Focus on the TextBox within that ListViewItem.

```
<ListView ItemsSource="{Binding Items, Mode=OneWay}">
  <ListView.ItemTemplate>
    <DataTemplate>
      <Grid>
        ...
        <TextBox Grid.Row="0" Grid.RowSpan="2" Grid.Column="1" Text="{Binding Value, Mode=TwoWay, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}">
          <i:Interaction.Behaviors>
            ...
          </i:Interaction.Behaviors>
        </TextBox>
      </Grid>
    </DataTemplate>
  </ListView.ItemTemplate>
</ListView>
```

What's the best way to implement this in an MVVM style?

Answer (score 0):

That sounds like a pure view issue, and should thus be solved purely in the view. It might need some code behind, however. Also one question: How likely is it that you will never need to select the ListView Item itself? If it is not 100% likely, consider a way to still select it directly (like doubleclick).

These answer seems similar enough:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/40054140/3346583 (event handlers and itterating over elements)
https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/1d52e0db-eef6-4022-9d27-ef456ad795a9/uwp-i-cant-set-focus-on-a-text-box-in-listviewitem?forum=wpdevelop (using the dispatcher)
I searched for "UWP ListView Focus Child". But looking for WPF solutions is about as likely to yield results.